JOOQ + PostgreSQL: how to cast String as Inet type during insert
What's the proper way to prepare an insert statement so a String representing an IP address can be inserted into a Postgres column of 'inet' type?
val rDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-12-29T02:47:17").toJavaLocalDateTime()
val iDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-12-29T22:11:00").toJavaLocalDateTime()
val ip = "192.168.1.10"




dslcontext.insertInto(IP_LIST)
    .columns(IP_LIST.RECV_DATE, IP_LIST.INSERT_DATE, IP_LIST.SENDER_IP)
    .values(rDate, iDate, ip)
    .execute()

I assume cast() should be applied to the value 'ip', but I've been unable to find a working example.
I've got jooq and org.jooq:jooq-postgres-extensions:3.19.11 installed and running ok, and
can do selects.
UPDATE
I checked jooq-generated table code and notice it sets 'sender_ip' field to String type. Is this correct, or should it be type Inet?
/**
 * The column <code>public.ip_list.sender_ip</code>.
 */
val SENDER_IP: TableField<IpListRecord, String?> = createField(DSL.name("sender_ip"), SQLDataType.VARCHAR.nullable(false), this, "")

Also, I'm using HikariCP as data source for jooq, and am using Kotlin v 2.0.0.
Here's build.gradle:
import nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*
    
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '2.0.0'
    id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '9.0'
}

group = 'org.me'
version = '1.02'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
    runtimeOnly 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.6.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.6.0'

    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.2'
    implementation 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.1.0'

    jooqGenerator 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.2'
    implementation 'org.jooq:jooq-postgres-extensions:3.19.11'

    testImplementation 'io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core-jvm:5.9.1'

}


jooq {
    version = '3.19.1'  // default (can be omitted)
    edition = JooqEdition.OSS  // default (can be omitted)

    configurations {
        main {  // name of the jOOQ configuration
            generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation = true  // default (can be omitted)

            generationTool {
                logging = Logging.DEBUG
                jdbc {
                    driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
                    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/iplist'
                    user = 'iplist'
                    password = 'xxxxxx'
                    properties {
                        property {
                            key = 'ssl'
                            value = 'false'
                        }
                    }
                }
                generator {
                    name = 'org.jooq.codegen.KotlinGenerator'
                    database {
                        name = 'org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
                        inputSchema = 'public'
                        forcedTypes {
                            forcedType {
                                name = 'varchar'
                                includeExpression = '.*'
                                includeTypes = 'JSONB?'
                            }
                            forcedType {
                                name = 'varchar'
                                includeExpression = '.*'
                                includeTypes = 'INET'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    generate {
                        deprecated = false
                        records = true
                        immutablePojos = true
                        fluentSetters = true
                    }
                    target {
                        packageName = 'nu.studer.sample'
                        directory = 'build/generated-src/jooq/main'  // default (can be omitted)
                    }
                    strategy.name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.named('generateJooq').configure { allInputsDeclared = true }

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(21)
}

UPDATE Two
When I converted the 'ip' field string to Inet, the Idea syntax checker complains that it wants a String for that value.
QUESTION: if all was working properly, is the syntax for the
.insertInto() command below correct?
fun String.toInet(): Inet {
    return inet(InetAddress.getByName(this))
}

dslcontext.insertInto(IP_LIST)
    .columns(IP_LIST.RECV_DATE, IP_LIST.INSERT_DATE, IP_LIST.SENDER_IP)
    .values(rDate, iDate, ip.toInet())
    .execute()

If I use a String for 'ip' instead, syntax checker complains on .execute command with a jooq DataAccessException
ERROR: column "sender_ip" is of type inet but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. Position: 134 

Taking Lukas Eder's advice, I added dependency on 'org.jooq:jooq-postgres-extensions:3.19.11' to the jooq{} block in build.gradle.
I couldn't add directly to the 'generator' block; the two sections that allow a dependency{} clause were @ the jooq{} root level and the main {} level--I added the dependency to both.
with generationTool{} logging set to Logging.DEBUG, I get the following output on db schema generation for the IP_LIST table. For some reason, the 'Forcing type' message was repeated 20 times:
16:26:57 INFO Generating table records 
16:26:57 INFO Generating record        : IpListRecord.kt
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>
16:26:57 INFO Forcing type             : public.ip_list.sender_ip to <priority>0</priority><name>varchar</name><autoConverter>true</autoConverter><includeExpression>.*</includeExpression><includeTypes>INET</includeTypes><nullability>ALL</nullability><objectType>ALL</objectType>

It appears that the jooq generator is reading the schema correctly, and recognizes that 'sender_ip' is of type 'Inet'.
Could the repetition of the 'Forced type' info message in log output be an indication that something is wrong?
If not, I'm still left with the question of how to properly format my Insert command so that it accepts the Inet type.

This would be so much easier and cleaner using native SQL.

@Stefanov.sm: Not really such a useful comment, don't you think? Specifically in this case, once this works, you never have to think about how to bind an inet bind variable to a JDBC prepared statement.

@LukasEder: This is not really my point. I think that expressing declarative logic in imperative manner using a proprietary (and not very nice, to word it softly) syntax instead of a clear standard one is generally not a good idea.

@Stefanov.sm: That is obviously your point, indeed. But the question is about jOOQ and it's a valid question about jOOQ. The OP probably didn't realise how to instantiate a Inet instance. How does your comment help the OP?

If you have put the jooq-postgres-extensions library on both the code generator's and the runtime's classpath, you don't have to do anything specific. Just wrap your value in org.jooq.postgres.extensions.types.Inet and use it, e.g.
Inet ip = Inet.inet(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.1"));

dslcontext.insertInto(IP_LIST)
    .columns(IP_LIST.RECV_DATE, IP_LIST.INSERT_DATE, IP_LIST.SENDER_IP)
    .values(rDate, iDate, ip)
    .execute()


Thanks for the casting solution. But, this shifts the syntax error from 'execute()' which warns about the wrong type of 'String' for 'inet' field, to '.values', which expects ip value to be 'String!'. I have the pg extensions implementation statement in Dependencies block in Gradle. Is their some other config that's required, like within jooq code generator block? (This is in Idea, BTW).

@bigswifty: You can edit your question and add details to it, which are relevant to answer your question. E.g. your complete gradle script.

@bigswifty: OK, so just add the jooq-postgres-extensions dependency also to the code generator's classpath (jooqGenerator)
